# « Hadjdj » est-elle une variante orthographique acceptée en français ?

Tags: orthographe, étymologie, arabe

Le mot « hadj » désigne le pèlerinage à La Mecque. La variante orthographique « hadjdj » est-elle également admise en français, bien que le dédoublement de la finale « dj » soit phonétiquement inutile ?

Comment: D'après Google les deux versions sont utilisées. Qu'est ce que tu entends exactement par "**être admise en français**".

Comment: @Fractaliste Parfois des anglicismes ont un équivalent en français et les professeurs nous demandent d'éviter les anglicismes. Dans le même ordre d'idées, je me demandais si certaines orthographes sont **à privilégier**, voire si certaines doivent être évitées pour des raisons étymologiques, par exemple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certains dictionnaires (par exemple [le Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/_%C2%A0hadjdj/38820)) utilisent la graphie « hadjdj » comme vedette et donnent « hadj » en équivalence.

Cependant, il semble que la graphie « hadj » soit la plus attestée, tel que le souligne [le Trésor de la langue française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hadj) :

> Nombreuses var. aux XIX<sup>e</sup> et XX<sup>e</sup> s. *Hadj* [adʒ] et *hadji* [adʒi] init. asp. sont les plus attestées sur toute la période considérée.

[Le dictionnaire de l'Académie](http://atilf.atilf.fr/academie9.htm) note que « hadj » est emprunté de l'arabe *hadjdj*.

Il est souvent difficile de savoir si un terme emprunté à une langue étrangère est « accepté » ou non en français. Les ouvrages de référence peuvent dire une chose et l'usage peut être tout autre. Dans ce cas-ci, l'utilisation de la graphie la plus attestée, soit « hadj », est probablement préférable, bien que « hadjdj » soit accepté par certains dictionnaires.